# Compile Java Library (.jar) for Linux on Windows

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I am using the MATLAB Library Compiler to compile a Java .jar on Windows. In my project I have some precompiled mexw64 and mexa64 files. The problem is that mexw64 files are automatically selected. How do I select mexa64 instead. Manually adding them to the project causes problems with *mexa64.auth files:

```
Cannot find authentication file '/tmp/.mcrCache8.3/apply_0/brain/spm8/spm_existfile_mexa64.auth'
```

Comment: It looks like if you are compiling on Windows, you can only compile a working .jar for Windows.  If you want to compile for a different platform, you have to compile on that platform.